# Visual hierarchy of contact form, testimonials on homepage?

Tags: layout

How high should a contact form, testimonials, and business contact info rank in the visual hierarchy on a homepage for a local business? Higher than content that provides "ins" to other pages like services, contact us, etc?

A file for a visual example: http://www.cameron.thejoosebox.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/new.png (its a 1.8M file, will take a second to load).

What are your thoughts? I think in the context of a local business like a moving company, people are more interested in seeing some testimonials, contact info, etc than they are in seeing a detailed description of your services, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no definite answer. Customers of all businesses are different. The easiest way to do this is to find about a dozen potential customers/website visitors, give them index cards with each of the sections written on an individual card, and ask them to sort the cards in the order of importance. Then, do statistical analysis of the results to figure out the average level of preference - that will drive your IA.

Comment: Nice answer, I think a card sort is a good way to go about getting that answer. Do you know of any online services that handle this?

Comment: It should also be dependent on what actions the business wants from the site. We have big buy-now buttons for a reason ;)

Comment: @adrianh: Yes. Some elements should have a higher priority regardless of card sorting results.

Answer (score 1):

I generally look at UX as what I am trying to get the user to do. The example on the left does not invite me to submit the form. It does invite me to learn more about 'our moving services', 'find answers' and 'call ..'. The example on the right invites me to use the form. If generating sales leads via the form is what you are after (which probably it should be), the example on the right seems more successful to me.